# I have a JQuery working but little buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery

On hover I want to hide span(options) and show span(options2) and when the pointer out of that span it will it will be back to normal stage like span(options2) hide and span(options) show.
Some time it work but some time the span(options2) shows and not hide after pointer out of the span it stuck and continuously show the span(options2) until we don't hover again.

HTML:

```
<div class="layer"> <span class="pull-left circle border-solid full"><i class="flaticon stroke checkmark-1"></i></span>
    <span class="pull-right options"><ul class="null"><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></span>
    <span class="pull-right options-2">
               <ul class="null">
                    <li><a href="#fakelink"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fakelink"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 null">
        <button class="btn btn-layer">Preview</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(this).find('.layer').find('.options').hover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent('.layer').find('.options-2').show();
    $(this).parent('.layer').find('.options-2').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent('.layer').find('.options').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm under the impression that is not the whole code. Why don't you make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.org ?

Comment: @lonut hope you get the code now

Comment: Why you are using `$(this).find('.layer')`?

Comment: @Satpal because this is selecting the parent

Comment: When binding the event `$(this).find('.layer').find('.options').hover(function () {` why are you using `$(this)`?

Comment: because I have multiple layers so I want to select just on which the function is performing may be I am wrong because I am new to it

Comment: @Satpal thanks for help I am evry thankful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `mouseout` event handler outside. Also `.prev()` and `.next()` can be used as `.options` and `.options-2` are siblings.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.layer .options').hover(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('.options-2').show();
  });

  $('.layer .options-2').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev('.options').show();
  });
})
```

```css
.options-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer">
  <span class="pull-left circle border-solid full">
    <i class="flaticon stroke checkmark-1"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="pull-right options">
    options
  </span>
  <span class="pull-right options-2">
    options-2
  </span>
</div>
```